# need regular expression in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have a problem to create the right regular expression for the result I needed. I looked everywhere and tried by myself but I got stuck and this what I get now:

```
NSString *searchText = @"{  124.0, 0.90, 0.556 }  { 127.9, 0.9764, 0.456 }"; 
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression  regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\{(.+\\d+[\\.]\\d+.+)\\}" options:0 error:nil];


NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:searchText
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, searchText.length)];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *r in matches)
{
    NSRange numberRange = [r rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@", [searchText substringWithRange:numberRange]);
} 
    result
    124.0, 0.90, 0.556 }  { 127.9, 0.9764, 0.456  
    instead off 2 times a numberRange without curlybraces

    124.0, 0.90, 0.556
    127.9, 0.9764, 0.456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regEx can be simpler, anything inside `{` and `}`.

```
NSString  *searchText = @"{  124.0, 0.90, 0.556 }  { 127.9, 0.9764, 0.456 }";
NSStriong *pattern    = @"\\{\\s+([.0-9, ]+)\\s+\\}";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression  regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:searchText
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, searchText.length)];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *r in matches) {
    NSRange numberRange = [r rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@", [searchText substringWithRange:numberRange]);
}
```

> 124.0, 0.90, 0.556
>   127.9, 0.9764, 0.456

Comment: Hello thanks its working but i have one question about your solution just to really understand.

        d+[\\.]\\d+  part off the regex off mine is the same as  [.0-9, ] or floating point numbers.  right? what does the whitespace after the comma?

Comment: The whitespace the between the numbers, without it only one number is selected.